# How to setup and manage a shared hosting server on Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Edition?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

### Background

I am a newbie in using Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Edition (and other editions as well).
I have a static IP, a very fast internet connection, a server (PRIMERGY TX100 S1 Server) and Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Edition (trial version).

The objective is to setup the server to be a shared hosting server such that each of my friends has a private account

- to manage his/her domain.
- to upload his/her web content to the server using the encrypted ftp.
- to manage database administration.
- to manage Certificate.
- etc

### Questions

1. Is there a good reference to learn "how to setup and manage a shared hosting server on Windows Server 2008 R2" ?
2. What are the rough steps I have to do to accomplish my objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Hosting Guidance for the Microsoft Web Platform](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/31/hosting-guidance-for-the-microsoft-web-platform/)

Play with deploying and configuring hosted websites at 
[TechNet Virtual Lab: Implementing Preliminary Shared Hosting Guidelines and Shared Configuration](https://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?EventID=1032361206&EventCategory=3&culture=en-US&CountryCode=US)

The [hosting days archive](http://www.microsoft.com/hosting/en/us/events/hostingdaysarchive.aspx) has alot of great presentations:

Last but not least the [hosting website](http://www.microsoft.com/hosting/en/us/hostingproviders/default.aspx) is where you will find additional general direction, of course the one thing you won't find there is the licensing info.  For that you need to go to the partner website to look into the [Service Provider License Agreement](https://partner.microsoft.com/40012010).  SPLA is the only way to legally provide hosted services with microsoft products.  While I believe you can use web edition, it might not be the best fit after reviewing the SPLA options.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will vote up later because it need 15 reputations to do it.

Comment: Also consider using WebSitePanel which is an open source control panel that will make it easy for you to expose the system settings to your customers in a secure way. http://www.websitepanel.net/